# Missing inset for buttons in UINavigationBar of UINavigationController inside UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

So, this is the deal.

I have an `UITabBarController` that has 4 `UINavigationControllers` as his childs.

What is happening is that when I setup the project this way, the buttons (***back button and the ones I could possible put at the right side***) appears with no offset (no margin relatively to the borders of the screen).

> This can be *easily* solved with many of the solutions around.

**But**, *and here this starts to get interesting*, the thing gets messy when I present a **modal view**. When I return from the presented view the buttons move to the expected position.

> PS: I had the same `UINavigationbar` outside of the
>   `UITabBarController` and this issue was not happening.

[image: Before Modal]
Before Modal

[image: After Modal]
After Modal

Any ideas as of why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: I had similar problems with view because i didn't call super in `viewWillApear` in my controller. So check that you call super methods....

Comment: @user1941284 no missing call to super in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear in code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a constant space so that it won't change:

```
 var negativeSpacer:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: self
    , action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = -5; // set the value you need
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [...] //your left bar items
```

Comment: Already tried that, this is one of the solutions I was talking about, the buttons moves when returning from the modal.

Comment: Think of it as the navigationbar re-layout itself and then apply the offset it was missing. So, any extra buttons (hacks) get's displaced too

Comment: What have you set your `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to? It has to be true.

Comment: I have no calls to that function in my entire code. Should I force it?

Comment: No it'll be default set to `TRUE`. Don't bother about that. Try my new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can save the last view controller selected in the tab bar like:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.previousViewControllerIndex =     // get index of your tab here

}
```

And after dismissing the modal view, `viewDidAppear` will be called on your UITabBarController, and you can programatically select the previous selected controller

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = previousViewControllerIndex
}
```

Comment: Any reason for this to work? When I return from Modal I'm already on the same view I had selected in my tabbar.

Comment: Ok, I tried this, not working also (as I was thinking would be) this do not appear  to has any base. If you think I'm wrong please go ahead and correct me. But I already tried that and it's a no go. :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's something weird going on here.

I had to manually add a `UINavigationController` as the parent of my `UITabBarController`. 
Also, I had to set its `hidden` property to `true` in order to get it out of the way.

If anyone finds a better solution or explains here why this is happening the **correct** answer goes straight to him/her.